# Silverlight in aspx page not loading

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have developed a simple Silverlight control. I created this by using the Silverlight application project template in VS 2008, adding a test page to my existing website.

Now, my control works perfectly in the auto-generated aspx, where I have now got it functioning as required. However, when I try to put the control in a new page it does not load. Debugging suggests that the code is all executing, however the UI I expect to see simply isn't appearing.

I tried this initially in a content page using the correct master page for my site layout, and then just in a standard ASPX which doesn't use MPs...same problem.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Am I missing something simple!?

So frustrating, any help appreciated!

Comment: Is your code requesting resources from a remote server by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Firebug or Internet Explorer's developer toolbar (and Fiddler) to see if the xap file is being requested and the rendered object tag has the proper size. If using the  control check for any JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the region where the Silverlight control should be to see if you get a Silverlight options prompt. That will tell you if the problem is in the loading of your Silverlight object into the page, or after the Silverlight plugin has loaded.